# How to handle empty returns of "find" in Armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have an `ivec C1` and did, say, `sum( C1.elem(find( C1==1 )) )`.

I hoped to get a zero return if no element in `C1` is 1, but instead it gave me an error saying that **Mat::elem(): given object is not a vector**.

I tried to use `(find(C1==1)).is_empty()` but this was not accepted as it told me it doesn't provide an `is_empty` method for the return of `find`. Then I tried to `conv_to<uvec>::from(find(C1==1))` but when `C1` is indeed empty it doesn't allow such conversion.

Anyone can help me out of this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work around the issue.
Change:

```
sum( C1.elem( find(C1==1) ) )
```

to:

```
sum( C1.elem( uvec(find(C1==1)) ) )
```

The output of sum() for empty vectors should then be zero.